# Google Analytics report detailing major iOS versions

Tags: google-analytics

I need to create a report in GA, which shows the share of major iOS versions: 6, 7 and 8. It's quite easy to add the dimension for operating system version, but it has all the minor versions (21 different versions at the moment). I'd like a dimension which only includes major versions.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics does not separate out major and minor versions of browsers or OS as dimensions.   This means that You cannot produce your desired report from within Google Analytics.

If I click into the iOS operating system report, I can get it graphed like this:

[image]

As you point out, that pie chart has multiple slices for iOS 8.  The only recourse is to create the graph that you want externally.  Luckily, you can download the CSV data.  When I do so, I can run it through a Perl script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $total = 0;
my $major = {};

while (my $line = <>){
    if ($line =~ /^([^,]+),((?:\"[^\"]+\")|[^,]+)/){
        my ($version, $sessions) = ($1, $2);
        $version =~ s/\..*//g;
        $sessions =~ s/[,\"]//g;
        print "$version $sessions\n";
        $major->{$version}=0 if (!$major->{$version});
        $major->{$version} += $sessions;
        $total += $sessions;
    }
}

for my $version (sort {$major->{$b} <=> $major->{$a}} keys %$major){
    my $sessions = $major->{$version};
    my $percent = sprintf("%.2f",$sessions/$total*100);
    print "$version\t$percent\n";
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
7   56.77
8   33.99
6   6.25
5   1.86
4   0.69
(not set)   0.29
3   0.15
2   0.00
10  0.00
```

Which I can then [graph](http://savvyroo.com/chart-1235417559633-ios-usage-by-major-version-for-october-2014):

[image]

Comment: Nice bit of code. It would be great to collect various helpful webmaster scripts like this and reference that in a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the operating system section of the report just tap on the specific operating systems you want to gather data about. And then compare those 3 in a separate graph in a custom report.